# Erro JSON.parse: Unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando pegar a resposta de uma requisição xhr:

```
...
xhr.send(formData);
var resposta = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
console.log(resposta); 
...
```

O console apresenta este erro:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
```

Mas não estou conseguindo ver onde estou errado. Quando tento:

```
console.log(xhr);
```

O console retorna tudo certo.

```
XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: null, 
readyState: 1, 
timeout: 0, 
withCredentials: false, 
upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload…}
onabort: null
onerror: null
onload: null
onloadend: null
onloadstart: null
onprogress: null
onreadystatechange: null
ontimeout: null
readyState: 4
response: "true"
responseText: "true"
responseType: ""
responseURL: "******"
responseXML: null
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
timeout: 0
upload: XMLHttpRequestUploadwithCredentials: false__proto__: XMLHttpRequest
```

Comment: Essa mensagem significa que a string tem um formato incompatível na conversão para JSON. Consegue nos mostrar como é saída @AmandaLima?

Comment: Quando tento mostrar `xhr.responseText` no console, sai em branco. Quando verifico o tipo de `xhr.responseText`, é do tipo string.

Comment: responseText: "true". Isso não é um JSON valido. Doc: http://www.json.org/json-pt.html

Comment: Como posso obter o `xhr.response` então?

Comment: Teu problema a principio não é com JavaScript. Você vai ter que alterar no servidor que fornece essa resposta. Se você não tem controle desse servidor. Poderá altear o JavaScript e não tratar a resposta com JSON.

Comment: Seria dessa forma: xhr.responseText. Mas isso não contem um JSON valido, de acordo com o log que você mostrou. Então o problema ta explicado.

Comment: Como é que está a parte que você define a url? dessa forma:   `xhr.open("GET", "ajax.php", true);` ?  Com true como último parâmetro?

Comment: @mauhumor melhor não sugerir que ela use uma requisição síncrona...

Comment: na vdd, pretendia identificar o problema, antes de propor solução.

Comment: Consegui resolver, coloquei a solução em uma resposta

Answer (score 6):

Consegui resolver o problema!

Adicionei esta linha antes de enviar a requisição, informando que a resposta será do tipo texto:

```
xhr.responseType="text";
xhr.send(formData);
```

Depois adicionei o trecho abaixo, para obter a resposta da requisição quando estiver concluída:

```
xhr.addEventListener('readystatechange', function() {
    console.log(xhr.responseText); 
});
```

Comment: Edita a pergunta.

Comment: @mauhumor, não se deve editar com a solução, senão as respostas em baixo perdem a coerência, acho que como a Amanda fez, fez bem

Comment: Na verdade, dentro desse evento você precisa fazer duas verificações, como a outra resposta indica.

Comment: isso vale para wordpress? Pois tenho o mesmo erro...

Answer (score 2):

Olá Amanda o teu responseText não é um JSON válido, visto que contém apenas uma string "true".

```
responseText: "true"
```

Acho que neste caso não precisa fazer parse.
Um exemplo de JSON válido (retornado pelo servidor) seria:

```
{"resultado": "true"}
```

**Update**

Conforme os comentários abaixo, deve estar acontecendo de você tentar pegar o resultado antes da requisição ter retornado.
Então vou deixar aqui um exemplo de requisição.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567114/how-to-make-an-ajax-call-without-jquery

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function loadXMLDoc() {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE ) {
           if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
               document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
           }
           else if (xmlhttp.status == 400) {
              alert('There was an error 400');
           }
           else {
               alert('something else other than 200 was returned');
           }
        }
    };

    xmlhttp.open("GET", "ajax_info.txt", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Então como pego o responseText?

Comment: Na verdade você está fazendo isso nesta linha: var resposta = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText); . Tem como postar seu código back-end para a gente ver como está sendo feita a resposta da requisição?

Comment: @Amanda `var resposta = xhr.responseText`

Comment: retorna sempre uma string.

Comment: @bfavaretto, assim não funciona, retorna uma string vazia.

Comment: Tem como mostrar o código completo da requisição? Pois se tiver fazendo isso de forma assíncrona. Não vai conseguir pegar o conteúdo da resposta logo após o método send.

Comment: O problema não é o formato, `JSON.parse("true");` não deveria falhar: https://jsfiddle.net/ncjbastb/

Comment: É verdade, o problema é que a requisição é assíncrona

Comment: E você tem razão @Renan, strings são JSON válido

Comment: Obrigado, vou atualizar minha resposta. Acho que o problema deve ser de fato a requisição é assíncrona.

Comment: Realmente, este era o problema! Consegui resolver, vou postar uma resposta com o que fiz

Comment: então ... de nada :D

Answer (score 0):

buscando por uma resposta sobre o mesmo erro, acabei descobrindo que na string de retorno contia caracteres acentuados e após remover funcionava, então foi ai que mudei o formato ao salvar o arquivo para utf-8 pois estava no ANSI e resolveu o problema (pra mim).

Answer (score 0):

Putz
Eu fiz diferente e tomei o mesmo erro. O que eu fiz foi uma chamada ajax com o Jquery desta maneira:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/post/updatetags",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(obj),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log("resposta: " + data)
        console.log("as tags foram atualizadas com sucesso!!!");
    },
    error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log("jqXHR: " + jqXHR.status);
        console.log("textStatus: " + textStatus);
        console.log("errorThrown: " + errorThrown);
    }
});
```

Ele chegava no controller, mas sempre dava o problema. Retirando o

```
dataType: "json"
```

resolveu o problema

Answer (score -1):

Vale apena verificar também se esta usando o PUT POST GET correto assim como os Pathvariable e o RequestParam